# error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘BusRoute’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} from type ‘void *’

Tags: c, pointers

I created a typedef struct named BusRoute and a pointer to an array of BusRoute named ActiveBusRoutes.

```
typedef struct 
{
    unsigned int busRouteNumber;
    char* startingLocation;
    char* endingLocation;
    Time routeStartTime;
    Time routeEndTime;
}BusRoute;



BusRoute* ActiveBusRoutes[100];
```

And I need a function to detect ‘empty’ elements in the ActiveBusRoutes array, i.e. wherever the pointer is NULL.

```
BusRoute* loopBus(){
    BusRoute* br; BusRoute* start=*ActiveBusRoutes;
    for( br=start; br<start + 100; br++){
        if(*br= NULL){
            return br;
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

When I use gcc to check, it report error, how to fix it plz

```
 error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘BusRoute’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} from type ‘void *’
   78 |         if((*br)= NULL){
```

Answer (score 1):

`=` means assignment and the code is trying to assign NULL where it shouldn't.

`==` means test for equality.

With a change, this will serve you better, but always ends on the first found empty slot in the array.

```
BusRoute **loopBus() {
    const int nRoutes = sizeof ActiveBusRoutes/sizeof ActiveBusRoutes[0];
    for( int i = 0; i < nRoutes; i++ )
        if( ActiveBusRoutes[ i ] == NULL )
            return &ActiveBusRoutes[ i ]; // ptr to empty spot in array

    return NULL; // No empty spots; all are used
}
```

EDIT: Now returns non-NULL pointer to first empty slot, or returns NULL if there are no empty spots... Notice function declaration.

Comment: Mb, but The rule with this work that prof assign to me is I must use pointer with this function. Could you please give me some advice with pointer of this function?

Comment: I've changed the code to what, to me, makes sense... If a slot is empty, it's index may be useful. It's value will be, of course, NULL... Returning NULL gives no information in this case. However, returning the ADDRESS of the empty slot may be useful. And returning NULL would mean there are no unused slots...